# finding the cheaper price in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a table in the following format

```
ID      Price
123     £12.99
123     £13.00
123     £12.99 
456     £21.99
456     £20.90
789     £18.99
789     £16.99
```

I'm trying to find the cheaper price based on the ID and the expected output should be in the following format

```
ID      Price      Cheap
123     £12.99     Cheaper
123     £13.00
123     £12.99     Cheaper
456     £21.99
456     £20.90     Cheaper
789     £18.99
789     £16.99     Cheaper
```

I'd like to know how to implement this in excel/googlesheets?

Comment: The `MIN` function? Or, a pivot table.

Comment: The question is unclear as Excel and Google Sheets could have several ways to achieve the same result.

Comment: If you found any of the answers helpful, feel free to say thanks by up voting them. If any of them have solved your problem, please mark the one you consider the best, as the correct answer by clicking the grey tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a MIN IF array function in Excel for this. The formula I entered in C2 is:

```
=IF(B2=MIN(IF(A$2:A$8=A2,B$2:B$8,"")),"Cheaper","")
```

Note that because it's an array formula, it must be committed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the following setup

[image]

Formula in C2 is

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(B2=MIN(IF(A2=$A$2:$A$8,$B$2:$B$8)),"Cheaper",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for nasty array formulas here:

```
=IF($B2=MINIFS($B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8,$A2),"Cheaper","")
```

[image]